# Get Parent HTML width from child button with image

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the array with nums of columns I would extract

```
leftPlace = <(number | undefined)[]>[];
```

In HTML I have button, which i click to extract column

```html
<th class="table-cell">
  <div class="table-cell-content date-column">
    <button (click)="sendLeft($event.target)" style="color: white;">
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'location-pin']"></fa-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</th>
```

The void which i use to extract width of column:

```
sendLeft(value?: EventTarget | null) {
  if (value instanceof Element) {
    this.leftPlace[this.columnCounter] = value.parentElement?.parentElement?.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.columnCounter++;
  }
}
```

If I do it with `<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'location-pin']"></fa-icon>`
it gives me the width of fa-icon, not parent object, i dont know why...

However if i use usual text in paragraph it work perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$event.target` to `$event.currentTarget`.

The `target` property from the event specify the element that dispatched the event, in this case, the element within the button (or the button itself) that was clicked, including the icon.

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

> The read-only target property of the Event interface is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched.

The `currentTarget` property from the event specify the element to which the event listener has been attached, in this case, the button itself.

From [MDN docs](https://The%20currentTarget%20read-only%20property%20of%20the%20Event%20interface%20identifies%20the%20current%20target%20for%20the%20event,%20as%20the%20event%20traverses%20the%20DOM.%20It%20always%20refers%20to%20the%20element%20to%20which%20the%20event%20handler%20has%20been%20attached,%20as%20opposed%20to%20Event.target,%20which%20identifies%20the%20element%20on%20which%20the%20event%20occurred%20and%20which%20may%20be%20its%20descendant.)

> The currentTarget read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to Event.target, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.